# Java Scanner can't read from only File Name

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, filenotfoundexception

I'm making a Java program to read some scores from a .csv file and calculate the average of those scores. To read from the file, I'm using the Scanner Class.

First, I create a scanner to read from my file:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("TempFile.csv"));
```

I expected this to work, but it returns a FileNotFoundException. So, I replaced TempFile.csv with the file's absolute file name.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(C:\\Users\....));
```

This gave me the result I wanted, and I was able to parse the file. I'm new to Java, but I know that it's bad practice to use the absolute file name.

How can I use only the short file name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File (new File("TempFile.csv").getAbsolutePath()));
```

Use above.

Comment: I don't understand. If `new File("TempFile.csv")` gives `FileNotFoundException`, then the line of code you posted **also** gives `FileNotFoundException`. I just tested it. What am I missing? I must be missing something, since your answer is the accepteed answer.

Comment: @Abra Verify that your file in in classpath.

Answer (score 0):

"TempFile.csv" is a relative path. It's relative to the working directory of your java program. This directory is the value of the `System` property "user.dir". The following line of code gives you that value...

```
String workingDirectory = System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

Hence if you are getting `FileNotFoundException`, it probably means file "TempFile.csv" is not located in the working directory of your java program.

By the way, since java 8, class `java.nio.file.Files` contains method [readAllLines](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-). So if file "TempFile.csv" is not too big, `readAllLines` may be a simpler alternative to class `Scanner`. Note though that you still need to provide the correct path to the file when calling that method.